# How to Select a date range from mysql while including other select variables

Tags: php, mysql, date, between

I have tried some of the solutions from the other questions but am having trouble still. I am throwing another Where clause in and dont know if that is what is messing it up.
The following was my last attempt using the suggested CAST from another similar question. MYSQL "date" is formatted correctly.

```
//set last 3 days for review retrial
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$past = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-14 days'));


$show_review_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM review WHERE status='1' AND entry_date BETWEEN $past AND $today ORDER BY entry_date");
```

This returns empty.

Comment: Take the string generated for your `mysql_query` command, look at it, and if at that point you don't see any issues with it, run it in a mysql console window and see what the results are. Hint... `'`

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I have put it into MYSQL and it returns empty. there are dates in that range and in the proper format.

Comment: Yes you get an empty result set, but you also get two warnings for your dates. Date literals need to be surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose your dates in single quotes:

```
$show_review_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM review WHERE status='1' AND entry_date BETWEEN '$past' AND '$today' ORDER BY entry_date");
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Be sure to call `mysql_error()`, which will point you to the source (if not the cause) of the problem.

```
$show_review_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM review WHERE status='1' AND entry_date BETWEEN $past AND $today ORDER BY entry_date");
if (!$show_review_query) {
   echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: Michael. Thanks. I had tried only back ticks.. DOH.. I will be error checking as you show here from now on. Thanks.